# C# MVC RedirectResult only if same URL not opened in browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have application where it will redirect to other application (other Domain) using C# MVC RedirectResult.

Currently the redirection is happening, but I would like to open the application (Redirect one) only if not opened already in browser. simply to avoid duplicate if already opened.

Please let me know if any feasibility

Answer (score 1):

This would not be possible because it would require possibly reading all the open tabs in browser to then do a comparison, which would be a privacy violation.